# Controlar estoque da loja virtual

Tags: php, mysql, sql, e-commerce

Estou em um projeto de loja virtual e tenho uma dúvida quanto a processo de controle de estoque.

Inicialmente estou fazendo tudo na tabela `product` onde tenho dois campos: `manage_stock` e `stock`. Manage Stock irá controlar se o produto terá ou não controle de estoque na hora das vendas e Stock é o estoque em questão.

Quando um pedido tiver seu status marcado como pago eu decremento direto no produto na coluna `stock`.

Segue estrutura da tabela:

```
Tabela product
id    name      manage_stock    stock
1     Mouse     0               NULL
2     Teclado   1               50
3     Monitor   1               10
4     Gabinete  0               5
```

Tabela product

Essa lógica está correta? ou devo criar uma tabela só pra o estoque vinculando o produto. A baixa no estoque é um simples decremento direto na tabela `produtc`?

Comment: Se cada produto tiver um stock assim como um stock só tiver um produto pode logo ter uma coluna de `stock` na própria tabela de produto

Comment: Votei para fechar como não clara porque só com estas informações só você pode responder isto.

Comment: Que informações sobre a lógica devo incluir na pergunta? Eu passei a forma que pensei estar certa e gostaria de saber se posso melhorar a lógica. @bigown o seu comentário poderia ser construtivo se você indicasse  como devo melhorar a pergunta ou a lógica

Comment: Colocando mais informações, eu não tenho como saber o que você precisa, o que você está fazendo. No momento a resposta possível é que pode ser melhor.Também pode não ser. A outra forma é fazer um tutorial completo sobre controle de estoque que, além de tornar a pergunta ampla, pode não servir pra nada para este caso. Controlar estoque costuma ser absurdamente mais complexo que isto. Mas se os seus requisitos forem estes, está tudo certo. Te ajudou em alguma coisa? Acho que não. A pergunta também não ajuda dar outra resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha visão do contexto:

Uma tabela para produtos;
Uma tabela para movimentação do estoque.

Na tabela de movimentação você controlaria as entradas e saidas dos produtos. Colocar tudo numa tabela só vai gerar dificuldades de escalabilidade da tua aplicação.

Comment: No caso ficaria com a tabela `product` e `product_stock` sendo que para cada entrada ou saída de produto eu teria um novo registro na tabela `product_stock`? A `product_stock` conterei as colunas `id` `id_product` `qtd` e `type`. A coluna type definiria se a movimentação é do tipo entrada ou saída. Seria isso Luciano Bezerra?

Comment: Sim, é uma abordagem válida, considerando a pouca quantidade de informações que temos a respeito do que você precisa.

Comment: De qualquer maneira sua resposta foi muito útil.